# How can i group an array and check for selected value using linq in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, linq

I have an array with a number of objects like the following:

Each object has the properties

```
        Name, Title, Selected.
```

I want to make sure that at least one item in each group is selected , if not return an error
saying please select an item in the group whatever it is by Entity.

So the list may be like this:

var myarray ==

```
      [0] ->Entity:"Name1", Title:"Mr", Selected:false
      [1] ->Entity:"Name1", Title:"Mrs", Selected:false
      [2] ->Entity:"Name1", Title:"Ms", Selected:true
      [3] ->Entity:"Name1", Title:"Miss", Selected:false
      [4] ->Entity:"Name1", Title:"Mr", Selected:false
      [5] ->Entity:"Name2", Title:"Mrs", Selected:false
      [6] ->Entity:"Name2", Title:"Mr", Selected:false
      [7] ->Entity:"Name2", Title:"Mrs", Selected:false
      [8] ->Entity:"Name2", Title:"Mrs", Selected:false
      [10] ->Entity:"Name2", Title:"Mrs", Selected:false
      [11] ->Entity:"Name2", Title:"Miss", Selected:false
      [12] ->Entity:"Name3", Title:"Mr", Selected:false
      [13] ->Entity:"Name3", Title:"Miss", Selected:false
      [14] ->Entity:"Name3", Title:"Miss", Selected:false
      [15] ->Entity:"Name3", Title:"Ms", Selected:false
      [16] ->Entity:"Name3", Title:"Ms", Selected:false
      [17] ->Entity:"Name3", Title:"Mr", Selected:false
      [18] ->Entity:"Name4", Title:"Mrs", Selected:false
      [19] ->Entity:"Name4", Title:"Mr", Selected:true
      [20] ->Entity:"Name4", Title:"Ms", Selected:false
```

In this scenario there would be a message saying
Please select at least one item in Entity , Name2,Name3 as Name1 and Name4 entities have at least one selected value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the items in Javascript by name as follows:

```
var map = items.reduce(function(m, current) {
  var currentValue = m.get(current.Name);
  if (currentValue == undefined) currentValue = false;
    m.set(current.Name, currentValue | current.Selected);
  return m;
}, new Map());
var withoutSelected = Array.from(map).filter(function(x) {
  return !x[1];
}).map(function(x) {
  return x[0];
});
```

Above code uses a map to group by name and to check whether any of the values in the group is selected. Then it converts it to an array that is filtered and mapped to only contain the group names that have no selected items.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32a4k5m1/1/).

Comment: thats in c# ? can i do it in angularjs ?

Comment: @Georgia sorry, somehow the question was shown in my C# questions list, but now it is Javascript.

Comment: brilliant , perfect  thanks . I used the following to make a string of the output  withoutSelected.join(", ");